# Bitcoin RPC createrawtransaction parse error

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, createrawtransaction

I try to create a raw transaction using the Bitcoin Core RPC through curl.

Python script:

```
import requests

data = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"curltext","method":"createrawtransaction", "params": [\'[{"txid":"bffa31485fe5bfbb7e86463ff6c7ee4f084936d54d0471fba7763538e7fd0aa6","vout":0, "sequence":1}]\' \'{"2Mt1FE9NVXP7fRYuPEZBHrFgoCEc4TGb2ZY":0.01}\']}'
print(data)
rawtx = requests.post("http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:18443", data=data).text
print(rawtx)
```

Output error:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"curltext","method":"createrawtransaction", "params": ['[{"txid":"bffa31485fe5bfbb7e86463ff6c7ee4f084936d54d0471fba7763538e7fd0aa6","vout":0, "sequence":1}]' '{"2Mt1FE9NVXP7fRYuPEZBHrFgoCEc4TGb2ZY":0.01}']}
{'result': None, 'error': {'code': -32700, 'message': 'Parse error'}, 'id': None}
```

I've tried escaping in multiple ways, but can't get it working.

Bitcoin CLI command:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"bffa31485fe5bfbb7e86463ff6c7ee4f084936d54d0471fba7763538e7fd0aa6","vout":0, "sequence":1}]' '{"2Mt1FE9NVXP7fRYuPEZBHrFgoCEc4TGb2ZY":0.01}'
```

Expected output (tx hex):

```
0200000001a60afde7383576a7fb71044dd53649084feec7f63f46867ebbbfe55f4831fabf0000000000010000000140420f000000000017a9140853562996d502a0abe2538657e5bf7bb261b6868700000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` string isn't correctly formatted JSON. This should be the correct version:

```
data = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"curltext","method":"createrawtransaction", "params": [[{"txid":"bffa31485fe5bfbb7e86463ff6c7ee4f084936d54d0471fba7763538e7fd0aa6","vout":0,"sequence":1}],[{"2Mt1FE9NVXP7fRYuPEZBHrFgoCEc4TGb2ZY":0.01}]]}'
```